# How to apply and view user roles?

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm trying to create custom model, and want it to work with custom roles. But I dont really understand how to do it. Also, i want to use my model with a qt widget, not with QML View. How roles are applying to certain items?
How to setup ListView, so that could work with my custom roles?

I know that I need to create enum, and reimplement roleNames function

my model .h file

```cpp
class ListModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int count READ count NOTIFY countChanged)

public:

    ListModel();
    virtual ~ListModel() override;

    enum CustomRoles{

        RoleType=Qt::UserRole+1,
        ButtonRole,
        CheckboxRole,

    };

protected:
    QList<BaseItems*> itemList;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> _roles;
   // int _RowCount = 0;

public:
    void Add(BaseItems* item);
    BaseItems* getItem(int index);
    void clear();
    int count() const;

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;

Q_SIGNALS:
    void countChanged();
};
```

my model .cpp file

```cpp
ListModel::ListModel() : QAbstractListModel()
{


}

ListModel::~ListModel()
{
    itemList.clear();
}


void ListModel::Add(BaseItems *item)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(),itemList.count(),itemList.count());
    itemList.append(item);
    endInsertRows();
    Q_EMIT countChanged();

}

BaseItems* ListModel::getItem(int index)
{
    return itemList.at(index);
}


void ListModel::clear()
{
    qDeleteAll(itemList);
    itemList.clear();
}


int ListModel::count() const
{
    return rowCount();
}


int ListModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent)
    return itemList.count();
}


QVariant ListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
     ItemButton *button = dynamic_cast<ItemButton*>(itemList.at(index.row()));

    if (!index.isValid())
            return QVariant();

    if (index.row() >= itemList.count())
            return QVariant();

    switch (role)
    {

    case Qt::DisplayRole:{
        return QVariant::fromValue(button->Text);}

    case ButtonRole:{
        return QVariant::fromValue(button->Text);}
    }

    return QVariant();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> ListModel::roleNames() const {

    QHash<int, QByteArray> role;
    role[RoleType] = "first";
    role[ButtonRole] = "last";
    return role;

}
```

Comment: Do you want to use your model with a Qt widget or a QML view?

Comment: I want to use it with Qt widget

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html is a good start for Qt Model/View

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "first" and "last" better you name the roles meaningfully:

```
QHash<int, QByteArray> ListModel::roleNames() const {
    QHash<int, QByteArray> role;
    role[RoleType] = "roleType";
    role[ButtonRole] = "buttonRole";
    return role;
}
```

So these quoted names will be used. If you want to display the data from this model in QML you can do something like this:

```
ListView {
    width: 100
    height: 500
    model: listModel
    delegate: Text {
        text: model.roleType + model.buttonRole
    }
}
```

listModel object can be initialized in C++ and can be passed to QML using

```
view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("listModel", listModel);
```

or you can make an instance of the ListModel in QML, but in the cpp file you will have to register your ListModel type

```
qmlRegisterType<ListModel>("ListModel", 1, 0, "ListModel");
```

then in the qml file:

```
import ListModel 1.0
```

finally creating an instance of the model by

```
ListModel {
    id: listModel
}
```